# How to echo a txt file with list of file names in each folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Let's say I have folder A and Folder B. Folder A has files A1 and A2. Folder B has files B1 and B2.

I want to create a text file in each folder that list the files in that folder. So create fileA.txt in folder A that list filenames A1 and A2 and same for B

Tried the following but didn't work

```
for /d %%g in ("*") do (
    for /r %%y in ("*.mp4") do (
        echo file '%%y'
    ) > ./%%g/mylist.txt
)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use `>>` to append to the file. A single `>` overwrites previous content, so only the last write persists.

Comment: @LotPings thank you so much. That got me one step further (below is my updated script). The problem now is that each of the files created in both Folder A and Folder B has the list of ALL the A & the B files. I wanna include only the A files in the mylist.txt created in the A folder and the B files for the text file in the B folder. Any suggestions? Thanks again!

`for /d %%g in ("*") do (`
`for /r %%y in ("*.mp4") do (`
`echo file '%%y' >> ./%%g/mylist.txt`
`)`
`)`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to achieve using the Command Prompt :

```
cd "\path\to\folder-A"
dir /b *.mp4 > fileA.txt
```

The switch `/b` will cause the listing of only the bare file names.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that's not what I really need. it's a huge number of folders and I need to automate it in a re-usable script (hence the batch file). Any advice on how to achieve that in a batch file is appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem in using `dir` in a batch script?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from `%Base%` folder this batch will iterate the folder structure and create `mylist.txt` containing all files of type `%ext%` found prepended with `file` and enclosed in single quotes.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\27\SO_1370390.cmd
@Echo off
Set "Base=X:\start\path"
Set "ext=.mp4"

for /R "%Base%" %%A in (.) do (
    ( for %%B in ("%%~fA\*%ext%") do Echo file '%%~fB'
    ) >"%%~fA\mylist.txt"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d /r . %%a in (*) do >"%%a\myList.txt" dir /b "%%a"
```

For each directory, recursively from current active directory send the result of bare `dir` command the the indicated file inside the directory being processed.